# RTS Game HTML5 Audio in Chrome MP3 and OGG Stutters and Stops

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

We're writting a Canvas demonstration Real Time Strategy (RTS) game in HTML5/JavaScript and have everything pretty much working. However, in Chrome (very latest version) the sound keeps stuttering and eventually just gives up. The code runs just fine in the latest Firefox, IE9 and Safari (though no sound at all on iOS4 iPhone/iPad but apparently that's a commercial decision by Apple). You can see for yourself on the link below just get more than a few sounds at once to cause the issue.

http://www.enterprisewarfare.com/Play.aspx

The simplified sound play code is below, note each sound exists 4 times (AUDIO_CHANELS_PER_FILE) to simulate more than one channel. Adjusting this number does not cause the sound loss any earlier or later so it is not to do with reaching the end of the array or playing the same audio object again. We've tried both OGG and MP3 file formats and everything works in IE9 (MP3) and Firefox (OGG) without issue. We've also tried seeking the file back to the begining to no avail.

```
    this.PlaySound = function(sId)
    {

        var iSoundMapIndex;
        var asoundChannels;

        if(sId == null || sId.length == 0) return;

        // Grab sound channels array
        iSoundMapIndex = this.SoundMap[sId];
        asoundChannels = this.Sounds[iSoundMapIndex];
        if(asoundChannels == null)
        {
            this.World.AddMessage("Unable to find sound \"" + sId + "\".");
            return;
        }

        // play the next in sequence
        asoundChannels[this.SoundChannel[iSoundMapIndex]].volume = 1;
        asoundChannels[this.SoundChannel[iSoundMapIndex]].play();
        this.SoundChannel[iSoundMapIndex]++;
        if(this.SoundChannel[iSoundMapIndex] == this.AUDIO_CHANNELS_PER_FILE) this.SoundChannel[iSoundMapIndex] = 0;

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in Chrome and It appears this has now been fixed. Still some issues with sound loading and more than one channel but the complete breakdown of sound seems to have been resolved.

Comment: Down-voted because you didn't bother to answer *how* the bug was fixed.

Comment: It was a bug in Chrome as in the browser itself not a bug only specific to Chrome but actually within Chrome. The Chrome team fixed the bug not me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is an issue with chrome and chromium. I'd suggest looking trough the bug reports and dev answers on them or just wait for it to be resolved and ignore the problem meanwhile.

It's a shame that no-one with more experience than me in javascript made any suggestions concerning a workaround. I've upvoted the question in the hope you'll find some help.